# How to disable fa icon in span when data is loading?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, redux-observable

I have anuglar 11 application. And I am using an icon to load a graph. But the time that the graph is loaded when the icon is triggered takes a long time. So to prevent that a user triggers many times the icon. I want to disable the icon till the graph is loaded.

So this is what I have for the icon:

```
<span    (click)="createChartFromMap(selectedSensor.sensor.charts[0],selectedSensor.properties['key'],selectedSensor.properties['name'] )"
    class="ml-auto "   >
    <fa-icon [icon]="selectedSensor.sensor.icon"  [styles]="{'color': '#BF0404'}" size="lg" class="menu-list-item">
    </fa-icon>
  </span>
```

and this is the method:

```
createChartFromMap(element: string, node: string, name: string) {
    const chartParams: ChartParams = new ChartParamsObj(
      node,
      DateTime.utc().startOf('day').toISO(),
      DateTime.utc().endOf('day').toISO(),
      'P1D'
    );

    const el = {
      config: {
        label: `${name}`,
        xrange: [
          DateTime.local().startOf('day').toFormat('yyyy-LL-dd HH:mm:ss'),
          DateTime.local().endOf('day').toFormat('yyyy-LL-dd HH:mm:ss')
        ],
        yrange:[0, 10]
      },
      type: element,
      paramObj: chartParams
    };

    this.mapRegistryService.components.load(el.type, el.config, el.paramObj);
  }
```

and the service that loads the data looks like this:

```
$blockButtonGraph: Observable<boolean>;

  components = {
    'area-chart':
    {
      component: AreaChartComponent,
      config: {
        grid: {          
          style: 'area-chart',
        },
        call: (params): Observable<WifiDensityDto[]> => {
          return this.wifiDensityService.getWifiDensities(
            DateTime.utc(params.start).startOf('day').toISO(),
            DateTime.utc(params.end).endOf('day').toISO(),
            params.node)
        },
      }
    },
    'line-chart':
    {
      component: LineChartComponent,
      config: {
        grid: {         
          style: 'line-chart'
        },
        call: (params) => {
          return this.cameraValuesService.cameraDataInInterval(
            params.start,
            params.end,
            params.node)
        }
      }
    },
    load: (comp, config, paramObj?) => {
      const cmp =JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.components[comp]));
      cmp.config.grid.label = config.label;
      cmp.config.grid.id = this.components.createUnId();
     
    },
    createUnId: () => {
      const id = new Date().getTime();
      return id;
    },
    register: (comp: any, injector: Injector) => {
      const factory = new WidgetFactory(
        this.components[comp.config.grid.name].component,
        {
          element: comp.config.grid.name,
          config: comp.config
        }
      );       
    }
  };
```

So I made a $blockButtonGraph observable.

But how to use now that observable?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

use `[disabled]` in your template. I'm not sure, but you might have to change your `<span>` to a `<button>` but it would look something like this:

```
<button 
    (click)=createChartFromMap(...)
    [disabled]=$blockButtonGraph | async>
</button>
```

Comment: $blockButtonGraph is in service

Comment: and how to initialize $blockButtonGraph?